# Windows named pipe in node js (preferred shared memory)

Tags: c#, node.js, windows, shared-memory, named-pipes

I am using named pipe to share some data between 2 processes in windows. One is a node process and other is a C# process. Here is a sample of code I use in my node process:

```
var net = require('net');

var PIPE_NAME = "mypipe";
var PIPE_PATH = "\\\\.\\pipe\\" + PIPE_NAME;

var L = console.log;

var server = net.createServer(function(stream) {
    L('Server: on connection')

    stream.on('data', function(c) {
        L('Server: on data:', c.toString());
    });

    stream.on('end', function() {
        L('Server: on end')
        server.close();
    });

    stream.write('Take it easy!');
});

server.on('close',function(){
    L('Server: on close');
})

server.listen(PIPE_PATH,function(){
    L('Server: on listening');
})
```

I use a NamedPipeClientStream in c# to read the data. I do this in a loop on both the sides, such as my node process is a producer and C# process is a consumer.

This works fine.

But sometimes the C# loop hangs and at that point in my node process I want to overwrite the new data over the old data. I was wondering if I can specify some max size in my pipe (the one I create in nodejs) or a timeout for the data but couldn't find such things in standard documentation.

If it cannot be solved this way, there is a shared memory route to solve the problem but I couldn't find any stable shared memory library for nodejs which works nicely on windows (and I don't have much time to write one right now). I need some pointers to move in the right direction.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT: I would really want to implement the above stuff using shared memory since I need to share large amount of data at a fast rate and I need to tweak for performance. Any pointers on how to implement it?**

Comment: I have no knowledge with c# or named pipes, but why not use plain TCP connection and just pipe the data?

Comment: The data I want to share is binary and big, and I do not want the overhead of TCP headers. I need a lightweight solution.

Comment: Could you share the C# example too? I also experiment how to connect C# .Net Core to Nodejs. I would try name piped first, I would like to achieve similar like reuse other apps http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/using-named-pipes-to-connect-a-gui-to-a/231903148. Did you try to just put the MemoryMappedFiles namespace code inside https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge. The performance should be bound by cpu and memory only, with the need of middleware as mention for the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a way to use the drain event in writable stream of nodejs as per my requirement.